# Combining Mineflayer and discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make it so whatever has been sent in the Minecraft chat is also sent to a Discord channel through my bot. It gets the message in-game however won't post to Discord channel. (I am new to JavaScript)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 62146,
    username: "email",
    password: "password",
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Connected!`)
    console.log(`Username: ${client.user.tag}`);
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {
    if (username === bot.username) return;
    bot.chat(message)
});

client.on("message", function(message) {
    client.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)
});

client.login('');
```

I am wanting this to send that message being sent by the user to so send to a Discord channel defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a few things you could improve here but the first thing that I knew how to solve (perhaps) was this:

In your code you have `client.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)`, when I'm pretty sure it should be `client.channels.get("500693869684326430").send(message)` as the function `get()` is what you are giving the parameter of the channel ID to. To be clear, this will send the `message` to the Discord channel with the ID `500693869684326430`.

I'm also seeing that while you say you're trying to get the messages from the Minecraft chat to send into the Discord channel, you seem to be sending the Minecraft chat message back into the chat with `bot.chat(message)`?
I believe you mean to use the aforementioned `client.channels.get("500693869684326430").send(message)` in here.

Just to clarify what I mean, I'll put the full code below.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 62146,
    username: "email",
    password: "password",
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Connected!`)
    console.log(`Username: ${client.user.tag}`);
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {
    if (username === bot.username) return;
    client.channels.get("500693869684326430").send(message)
});

client.on("message", function(message) {
    // you don't really need this but maybe that's what you want, i don't know
    //client.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)
});

client.login('');
```

To be fair, I've never used mineflayer before, but I thought I might be able to help with the order of things. If you need me to clarify anything just comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You Can Do It Like This

There is an event called "message" on the mineflayer

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  let channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHID")
  if (!channel) return;
  channel.send(`From Server Chat >> ${message}`)
})
```